# TypeError: .map is not a function don't understand what's wrong

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, components, typeerror

I don't understand why this component doesn't work
Here is link to img "because somehow i can't post image directly
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ax7im.png  Thank's for any help
Here you have code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Postitem from "./Postitem";

const Postlist=(post,title)=>{

return (
<div>
         <h1 style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>{title}</h1>
{post.map((post) =>
 <Postitem post={post} key={post.id}/>)};
</div>
 
)};
export default Postlist;
```

Comment: Is post an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React function components only ever take one argument, which is an object containing all the props. Assuming you are passing a `post` prop as an array when you are rendering it, fixing your function declaration to this will work:

```
const Postlist=({post,title})=>{
  // component body here, as above
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check, what is coming in the "post" variable to this component. If you use "post.map" function, then it must be an array.